# How to mock JQuery Ajax call along with Angular 2 component

Tags: jquery, ajax, angular, mocking, jasmine

We are working on an angular 2 app. For unit testing we use Jasmine as our framework. I am trying to write my first unit test for this setup.
We have a component, which calls a web service using $.ajax call and receives JSON data.
Code as below -

```
$.ajax({ url:(myurl), 
dataType: 'json', 
success:(returnedData) => {return myData;},
error:(returnedData) => {<log error>;
return}});
```

the data that is returned is in below format-

```
{
               "MyClass": {
                   "searchFilter": "test",
                   "additionalIdeas": "moretest",
                   "results": [
                        ["resA", "result A"],
                        ["resB", "result B"],
                        ["resC", "result C"]
                    ]

               },
               "DataFormat": 1
           };
```

in my unit test I am injecting component and service using testComponentBuilder and then trying to call the method which in turns calls the service to populate my data.

How can I mock the json data here? I tried looking at Jasmine-Ajax but got lost between inject and test builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it using Deferred objects. The code looks like.

```
spyOn($,'ajax').and.callFake(()=>{
    var d = $.deferred();
    d.resolve(myMockedJSON);
    d.promise();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically unit tests should not be trying to call external sources.  I would suggest you initiate a spy which does not allow the call to go out and assert it's called along with the arguments your piece of code should be called with, you can even mock a response.

As far as mocking JSON, what's the problem here?  just create a local mocked resource as a JSON object which is similar or identical to that which the ajax call would return.

Specifically you create a spy for the method name which makes the ajax call and stub the response with a mocked object.  You could even add a spy for your jQuery ajax call assuming you're using jQuery, for instance...

```
spyOn($, 'ajax').and.returnValue(yourMockedJsonObject);
```

http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies

Comment: I used that route, there it returns this.service.getData.done() is not a function. getData is the function where I call that ajax request. As you can see it uses success() there and not .done

Comment: correction in above statement.. .done is not used while making ajax call. Instead it is used in component class while making call to my service class method. The call looks like this -     this.myservice.getData(param1,param2).done(mydata=> { //further process data}